# How to get Absolute path of captured image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, uri

I am working on android selfie-app in which user will take selfie image or selfie-video and upload to the server.
Same code is working properly for Selfie-video but app has crashed for selfie-image. When I capture image after clicking on "ok" button, app will crash and get `NullPointerException` in `startActivityResult()` method. As far as I understand I am not getting absolute file path from Intent.

```
package com.pawras.selfi;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String selectedFilePath;
    ImageView bimage,bvideo;
    ArrayList imageList;
    TextView bimage_gallery,bvideo_gallery;
    //ProgressDialog dialog;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    String flag_value,thumbnail,email;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("filter",MODE_PRIVATE);
        email= mSharedPreferences.getString("isRegistered","no");
        if (email.equals("no")) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
        bimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
        bvideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videos);
        bimage_gallery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.img_gallery);
        bvideo_gallery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.videos_gallery);
        bimage.setOnClickListener(this);
        bimage_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
        bvideo_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
        bvideo.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == bimage) {

            //on attachment icon click
            imagecapture();
        }
        if (v == bvideo) {

            //on attachment icon click
            videocapture();
        }
        if (v == bimage_gallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery_images.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        if (v == bvideo_gallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gallery_videos.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
    private void imagecapture() {
        flag_value="1";
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //allows to select data and return it
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
        }
        else {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
        }
        //starts new activity to select file and return data
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
    }
    private void videocapture() {
        flag_value="2";
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //allows to select data and return it
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,10);
        //starts new activity to select file and return data
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
    }

    String selectedImagePath;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {
                if (data == null) {

                    //no data present
                    return;
                }
                final Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedFileUri);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "file path is"+selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("absolute",selectedFilePath);
                 if(flag_value=="2")
                  {
                        Bitmap thumb =ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedFilePath,
                                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                        flag_value=getStringImage(thumb);

//                      byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(flag_value, Base64.DEFAULT);
//                      Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                  } else{
                     flag_value="1";
                 }

               // Log.i(TAG, "tuumb nail string:" + thumbnail);
                Log.i(TAG, "Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

                if (selectedFilePath != null) {
                   // dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading File...", true);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {

                                uploadFile(selectedImagePath);

                            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insufficient Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please choose a File First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,null);

        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath) {
        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()) {
           // dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "suurce file does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return 0;
        } else {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(Constant.SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty(
                        "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    try {

                        //write the bytes read from inputstream
                        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insufficient Memory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(email);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"flag\"" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(flag_value);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);



               // get server ok responce
                try{
                    serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Memory Insufficient!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                   // imageList.add(selectedFilePath);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //reading server echo responce
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                final String stringResponse = sb.toString();
                Log.d("response string:", stringResponse);
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response string:"+stringResponse , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response string:"+stringResponse , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();

                if (wakeLock.isHeld()) {

                    wakeLock.release();
                }


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            //dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add error log also ?

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.